# Почему нельзя перегрузить конструктор numpy.ndarray?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

```
class A(numpy.ndarray):
     def __init__(self,x,y):
         print ('Конструктор')

a = A(2,3)
```

Выдаёт ошибку : TypeError: data type not understood
Если использовать один параметр.

```
class A(numpy.ndarray):
     def __init__(self,x):
         print ('Конструктор')

a = A(2)
```

То всё нормально, будет напечатано конструктор. Если нет параметров

```
class A(numpy.ndarray):
     def __init__(self):
         print ('Конструктор')

a = A()
```

То будет ошибка : TypeError: Required argument 'shape' (pos 1) not found
Почему нельзя перегрузить конструктор numpy.ndarray

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В [документации](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.subclassing.html) сказано, что при [перегрузке](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.subclassing.html#implications-for-subclassing) конструктора `ndarray` начинать необходимо с реализации метода [__new__](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__), так как там происходит большая часть работы по инициализации массива вопреки обычному `__init__`.
Вот простой пример из документации, где описаны три рекомендуемых метода, необходимых для инициализации:

```
import numpy as np

class C(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print('In __new__ with class %s' % cls)
        return super(C, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # in practice you probably will not need or want an __init__
        # method for your subclass
        print('In __init__ with class %s' % self.__class__)

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        print('In array_finalize:')
        print('   self type is %s' % type(self))
        print('   obj type is %s' % type(obj))
```

Там же приведены более расширенные примеры и подробное описание ролей каждого из методов-этапов конструктора.